# How do I refresh a class that retrieves dates after files changes are made?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I have class that retrieves a date from a certain file. After I make changes to that file I want that class to grab the new date but it keeps showing the original date. I’ve even tried creating a new instance of the class but I get the same results. What am I missing?

EDIT: Simply put, I'm looking to reload the class so it's cache is replaced.

```
namespace ProgramUpdater
{
   class clsGetFileDates
   {
       private DateTime eappwDateC = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"c:\files\eappw.exe");                          

       public DateTime EappwDateC         
       {                                
           get { return eappwDateC; }   
           set { eappwDateC = value; }  
       }                                
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe can You show us some code You tried?

Comment: Are you re-creating clsGetFileDates on each read?  If not, then the value would stay cached in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a look at the FileSystemWatcher class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

You can set up the FileSystemWatcher to notify you when just the LastWriteTime of your specific file changes, in which case it will call the event handler you specify. Within that event handler you can update your member variable.

Comment: I don't think this is required (at least doesn't seem to be on win7/VS2010 .Net 4.0).  It might speed up noticing the change without polling, but polling also seems to work.